# Converting images to video android

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I am using external camera with my application. The camera takes 9 pictures every second (9fps). The pictures are bitmaps 384x288. I need to create from this pictures a video file.

What I have tried:

- Using Jcodec

The problem: jcodec is relatively slow, and for it to work properly i add the bitmaps to ArrayList and when the record stopped i convert the array to video. I takes to much time. For 30 sec video there is about 1 min rendering time.

- Using native mediaCodec

The problem: I could only generate AVI files (video/avc) that not readable in the original android player. I can not use what is written here: http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/ because I developing for API 16. I have tried using (video/mp4v-es) but the video is corrupted and not playable in any player.

- Using FFmpeg

The problem: Very complicated to implement in android, and I am not sure it will give me the result I needed after spending time to implement this. The result I need is to record video streaming as I get the bitmap without any delay.

What can you suggest me?

Comment: You might be able to take the raw H.264 stream output by `MediaCodec` and convert it to .mp4 with ffmpeg as a second (relatively quick) pass.  I *think* you can do this by invoking ffmpeg as a command-line utility rather, than trying to build it as a library and access it from your app through JNI.  (This would be much easier with API 18, but looking at http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html I can see why you're targeting API 16.)